# MySQL datetime arithmetics

Tags: mysql, datetime

Can someone, please, explain me this behavior of MySQL?

**Query:**

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND - NOW() AS test;
```

**Result:**

- **130** - in cases when now() is in (00:00 - 00:29) interval
- **170** - in cases when now() is in (00:30 - 00:59) interval

I interpret the 130 result as "1 minute and 30 second". The 170 result is strange, I suspect it has something to do with minute overflow but I can not explain it.

Following query works OK (I mean - as I expected):

```
select TIMEDIFF( DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL 90 SECOND), now()) AS test;
```

Result: 00:01:30

Comment: I think date calculation using `+` and `-` is flawed (if not totally broken) in MySQL. Adding a number to a date returns a strange number not a date: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/13888 Just stick with date_add() and you should be fine.

Comment: Adding a number to a date returns date in YYYYMMDD format, that's perfectly OK and [documented]}(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-date), AFAIK.

Comment: No it's not a "date" it's a *number* (which is something completely different). And yes it's documented, but that doesn't make it less weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially, it seems to me the reason this is failing is because you can't subtract when the interval precedes the date.

```
SELECT INTERVAL 90 SECOND - NOW(); //..right syntax to use near '- NOW()'
```

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) states:

> `INTERVAL expr unit` is permitted on either side of the + operator if the expression on the other side is a date or datetime value. For the - operator, `INTERVAL expr unit` is permitted only on the right side, because it makes no sense to subtract a date or datetime value from an interval.

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND AS DATETIME) - CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME)
```

I also would most likely interpret `130` as 1 minute, 30 seconds, but what appears to be happening is that straight arithmetic is performed by subtracting the time parts (as integers, not time).

For 130:

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND AS DATETIME)
//June, 05 2013 13:10:50+0000

SELECT CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME)
//June, 05 2013 13:09:20+0000

SELECT CAST(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND AS DATETIME) - CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME)
//130

  1050
-  920
------
   130
```

For 170:

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND AS DATETIME)
//June, 05 2013 13:12:11+0000

SELECT CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME)
//June, 05 2013 13:10:41+0000

SELECT CAST(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 SECOND AS DATETIME) - CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME)
//170

   1211
-  1041
-------
    170
```

However, you should be using `INTERVAL` using the date functions (`DATE_ADD`, `DATE_SUB`) as they were intended seeing how something like above returns `130/170` when it should return `90`.